# Problem in showing that contours $\gamma_2$ is equivalent to $ \gamma $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, plane-curves

Let $\gamma_2(t)= e^{-it^2}, t\in[0,\sqrt{2\pi}]$ and $\gamma(t)=e^{2\pi it}, t\in[0,1]$ Show that $\gamma_2 \sim \gamma $.

I think that for the latter to be true $\gamma_2$ should be  $\gamma_2(t)= e^{it^2}, t\in[0,\sqrt{2\pi}]$

I have tried to prove  $\gamma_2 \sim \gamma $ for the original $\gamma_2$ by showing that $ \int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz $ for an arbitrary $f$ ,

but that $-$ in $e^{-it^2}$ messes up the integral limits producing

$ \int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz=\int_0^{-1}f(\gamma(t))\gamma(t)'dt $ instead of

$ \int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz=\int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\gamma(t)'dt=\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz $ .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by $\gamma_2\sim\gamma$? Does that mean they trace out the same contour? (Equivalently, does it mean they have same images?) Does it mean they're equivalent? (Meaning, each a reparametrization of the other.) Does it mean Does it mean that any two contour integrals of a fixed integrand of their images are equal?

Comment: My textbook uses this symbol to say that $\gamma_2$ is equivalent to $\gamma$

Comment: My textbook uses this symbol to say that $\gamma_2$ is equivalent to $\gamma$. And it further says that two equivalent curves (meaning, each a reparametrization of the other)  will have equal contour integrals of a fixed integrand of their images and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the following are equivalent? What would the reparametrizations be, explicitly?

1. $a:[0,\sqrt{2\pi}]\to \Bbb C:t\mapsto e^{-it^2}$
2. $b:[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb C:t\mapsto e^{-it}$
3. $c:[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb C:t\mapsto e^{it}$
4. $d:[0,1]\to\Bbb C:t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$

It might help to review what exactly a [reparametrization is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Reparametrization_and_equivalence_relation).

By the way, your integrals should have been

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{2\pi}}f(\gamma_2(t))\gamma_2'(t)dt \quad{\rm vs}\quad \int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt,$$

where $\gamma_2(t)=e^{-it^2}$ and $\gamma(t)=e^{2\pi it}$, exactly as you defined them. Can you simplify them now?

Comment: why should the integral for $\gamma$ be $\int_0^{2\pi}$ instead of $\int_0^1$ since for $\gamma , t\in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: the definition in my textbook requires $\phi '(t)>0$, not only $\phi'(t)\neq0$

Comment: @helplessKirk Oops, you're right on the first point. As for your second, if your textbook requires $\phi'>0$ then it's defining an equivalence of *oriented* curves. And $\gamma$, $\gamma_2$ are *not* equivalent as oriented curves, only as curves. (Indeed, if you compute the integrals, one should be the opposite of the other.) So something needs to be fixed or clarified.

Comment: thanks , I guessed that the problem was there , but I only knew the definition in my textbook and I thought something was wrong with my thinking.